# Prism template pack Add reference to mono android 8.1 But I did and still moaning

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Creating a new blank project using Prism template I keep getting

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Your project is not referencing the "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1"
>   framework. Add a reference to "MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1" in the
>   "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.  BlankApp3.Android

but I have

[image]

[image]

Using xamarin forms 3.1.0.583944

Am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the details of it. What happened to me is don't select the Use Latest platform..

Instead select Android 8.1(Oreo) it becomes working

If not working then too

In Android Options Untick the Use Shared Runtime.

In Android Manifest select Target Android version as "USE COMPILE USING SDK VERSION".

This sloved my problem I don't know the Details.